# solutions of the simultaneous congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, gaussian-elimination

I need to find the solutions of the simultaneous congruences
$$
\begin{aligned}
3 x+3 z & \equiv 1\pmod 5, \\
4 x-y+z & \equiv 3\pmod 5 .
\end{aligned}
$$

How to reduce this into the following ?

\begin{aligned}
&x \equiv u+2 v \equiv 2 v+2&\pmod 5, \\
&y \equiv v=v &\pmod 5, \\
&z \equiv t+u+3 v \equiv 3 v &\pmod 5 \\
&
\end{aligned}

Comment: How would you solve it over the rational numbers?

Comment: And we certainly don't know where you get $t,u,v$ from. There are a lot of closed forms for solutions of this sort, and duplicating a specific answer can be quite a bit of work.

Comment: For example, $(x,y,z)=(u,4+3u,2-u)$ also works.

Answer (score 1):

We are given :
$$\begin{aligned}  
(1) \ \ \ \ \ & 3 x + 0 y + 3 z & \equiv 1\pmod 5 , \\  
(2) \ \ \ \ \ & 4 x - 1 y + 1 z & \equiv 3\pmod 5 .  
\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}  
4 \times (1) \ \ \ \ \ & 12 x + 0 y + 12 z & \equiv 4\pmod 5 , \\  
3 \times (2) \ \ \ \ \ & 12 x - 3 y + \ 3 z & \equiv 9\pmod 5 .  
\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}  
(3) \ \ \ \ \ & 0 x + 3 y + 9 z & \equiv -5\pmod 5 , \\  
(3) \ \ \ \ \ & 0 x + 6 y + 8 z & \equiv 0\pmod 5 , \\  
(3) \ \ \ \ \ & 0 x + 1 y + 3 z & \equiv 0\pmod 5 , \\  
\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}  
1 \times (1) \ \ \ \ \ & 3 x + 0 y + 3 z & \equiv 1\pmod 5 , \\  
3 \times (2) \ \ \ \ \ & 12 x - 3 y + 3 z & \equiv 9\pmod 5 .  
\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}  
(4) \ \ \ \ \ & -9 x + 3 y + 0 z & \equiv -8\pmod 5 , \\  
(4) \ \ \ \ \ & 1 x + 3 y + 0 z & \equiv 2\pmod 5 , \\  
\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}  
(3) \ \ \ \ \ & y + 3 z & \equiv 0\pmod 5 , \\  
(3) \ \ \ \ \ & 2 y + 6 z & \equiv 0\pmod 5 , \\  
(3) \ \ \ \ \ & 2 y + z & \equiv 0\pmod 5 , \\  
(5) \ \ \ \ \ & z & \equiv -2y\pmod 5 , \\  
( \star 5 \star ) \ \ \ \ \ & z & \equiv 3y\pmod 5 , \\  
\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}  
(4) \ \ \ \ \ & 1 x + 3 y & \equiv 2\pmod 5 , \\  
(6) \ \ \ \ \ & x & \equiv 2-3y\pmod 5 , \\  
( \star 6 \star ) \ \ \ \ \ & x & \equiv 2+2y\pmod 5 , \\  
\end{aligned}$$

Hence , the Solution can be $(2y+2,y,3y)$ which is what OP wants to Derive.
We can verify that by using it in the given Equations.